# How to add div at the end of header in wordpress with php code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating a plugin and I want to create a full-width div at the bottom of the header. I tried wp_head action but it is adding the div at the top of the header.
The question is how can i add a div at the bottom/end of header with php code? Is there any wordpress hook or filter which I can use? Thanks in advance.

Currently, it appears like this.

[image]

But I want to move the breaking section below the header.

Comment: Can you add your code so we can help you better. It would help to see your hook code.

Comment: I have tried wp_head and wp_body_open hooks.  add_action('wp_body_open', 'ttbn_add_breaking_news_to_header');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no available WordPress hook that will run right after the WordPress header.php loads.

I implemented this by appending the HTML code below the header using javascript.

You can find the code here. https://github.com/AwaisTheDev/wordpress_breaking_news_plugin/blob/main/includes/load-widget-frontend.php#L82

Answer (score 0):

`wp_body_open` fires after the opening body tag but the header is after the tag. The action hook that fires after `get_header` would be `loop_start`, unless the theme has a hook added in between. Also make sure to set the priority so the hook loads first.

Styles

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
}
```

Function and hook

```
function namespace_my_function() {
?>
<div id="banner">
    <p>
        Breaking News! This is the banner for the news part of the header!
    </p>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'loop_start', 'namespace_my_function', 1 );
```

Comment: loop_start still prints the output before the website header template.